# Unity3d Accessing GameObject from thread: InternalGetGameObject error

Tags: c#, user-interface, tcp, unity-game-engine

I am using a custom TCP socket client class to connect to a server. When the server responds a specific message/command, I want to change the active menu but Unity3D tells me that accessing GameObjects from other threads but the main thread is not possible.

Currently I am working with a receive thread which uses blockin IO. I tried using BeginReceive to receive messages and wait for the specific command to then change the active menu but it gave me the same annoying error.

Is there a simple and nice way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you can not access GameObjects from other threads. You could implement a listener in main thread:

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(CheckOtherThreadsEveryFrame());
    StartCoroutine(CheckOtherThreadsOnceASecond());
}

IEnumerator CheckOtherThreadsEveryFrame(){
    while(true){
        //check if another thread has put some data where this method can see 
        yield return null; //wait until next frame      
    }
}
IEnumerator CheckOtherThreadsOnceASecond(){     
    while(true){            
        //check if another thread has put some data where this method can see           
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //wait for 1 second
    }
```